# Only one instance works with Azure October 2012 SDK on IIS7.5

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012, azure-web-roles, azure-sdk-.net

I just upgraded my Azure solution to VS2012 and October 2012 version. I have 2 webroles but only 1 of them is working now when I look it from IIS Manager. I'm sure of it because my webrole's inter-role communication requests are failing too.

First I tought it can be another problem so I asked this question: [Windows 8 Azure Emulator is Remapping Port 80 to 81](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272013/windows-8-azure-emulator-is-remapping-port-80-to-81)

Here you can see my IIS Manager:
[image: IIS WebRoles]

Comment: what does it say in the compute emulator in the system tray?

Comment: Interesting but it looks like normally working.

Comment: Ok, try checking the box 'use iis express' on the web project and keep an eye on the iis express system tray icon to see the urls that its making it accessible. remember port remapping is fine to 81 82 its perfectly normal. also what role communication are you doing? can you step through it to see whats happening?

Comment: IIS Express is crashing.

Comment: Yeah that doesn't sound too great; something is most definitely wonky on your end. Im running 4 webrole instances in iis express at the moment. take your solution apart one by one starting with the inner role communication and see where its falling over.

Comment: I removed everything else except simple html pages even entries in web.config and Role configuration files but still same. :/

Comment: repair that sdk installation imo. somethings horribly broken :P

Comment: I have windows 8 and windows 7 currently on my disk and both of them have the same issue. I hope I can find a way to fix it. Otherwise I'll have to stuck in 1.7. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: on Win8 with IIS Express8 works just fine with 3 and more instances (and less of course). Did you repair the SDK installation?

Comment: I did a repair and reinstall. I tried to create a new azure project with a basic ASP.NET WebRole but it failed too. I really don't know what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue, and RESOLVED it following the suggested Registry hack here:
[Strange behavior of Windows Azure Compute Emulator (SDK 1.8) with multiple role instances on a clean machine with VS2012 but WITHOUT VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13946634/strange-behavior-of-windows-azure-compute-emulator-sdk-1-8-with-multiple-role)

Anyone with this issue, please pile onto this connect log for MS to properly fix:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/773786/azure-sdk-1-8-binds-several-web-roles-to-the-same-port-on-local-emulator

Comment: thank you. I will try your solution. As soon as I get it working, I'll mark this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug, I hope it's fixed in the next update by Microsoft. Definitely happens if you have VS2012 on Windows 8 and didn't install/upgrade VS2010

Workaround:

- Create a text file (*.reg) with this and import into your registry (double click .reg file in explorer)

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\10.0]
>   "SP"=dword:00000001

- Kill the process i.e. exit VS2012, exit compute emulator (or just reboot if in doubt).
- Fire it up again!